# Magento 1 - Change Magento custom options date values

Tags: magento-1, custom-options, datetime

Hello I am simply trying to find the array of defaults for the product custom-option date

my goal is to change the month from "01,02,03....12" to a string with the month name "Jan. , Feb. , Mar. - Dec."

I believe I found the date custom-option file in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/Date.php
```

and in there you see the 'month' array being called but I can't find the declaration file.

I am new to this stuff so pardon my ignorance if this is obvious or I am making it more convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

The month select is generated in the method `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Date::getDropDownsDateHtml` by the line `$monthsHtml = $this->_getSelectFromToHtml('month', 1, 12);`.
You can change that to something that fits your needs.

or you can do an ugly thing and change the dropdown texts via some javascript after the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date.php

and add the below code into **Date.php** file.

> Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Date (its better to rewrite it in local)

```
protected function _getMonthSelectFromToHtml($name, $from, $to, $value = null)
{
        $options = array(
                array('value' => '', 'label' => '-')
        );
        for ($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i++) {
                $options[] = array('value' => $i, 'label' => Zend_Locale::getTranslation($i, 'Month', Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode()));
        }
        return $this->_getHtmlSelect($name, $value)
                ->setOptions($options)
                ->getHtml();
}
```

then find out

```
$monthsHtml = $this->_getSelectFromToHtml('month', 1, 12);
```

and replace with below code:

```
$monthsHtml = $this->_getMonthSelectFromToHtml('month', 1, 12);
```

Hope this helps.